# Center a dynamic width box

Tags: css

Pseudo HTML

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>Nav 1</li>
  <li>Nav 2</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I want this to look like

`[DIV---------------[UL nav1 nav2]----------------------]`

Instead I get

`[DIV[UL nav1 nav2-----------padding-------------------]]`

The li's are left floated. The ul has overflow: auto. How can I get the ul to be as wide as it needs to be, not as wide as it can be, so I center it with an auto margin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `display: inline-block` with IE hack:

```
zoom: 1;
display: inline;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
div { text-align: center; }
ul { display: inline; }
```

You may also want to try adding:

```
li { display: inline; }
```

Comment: I also need to set a height for it, so it must be a block. I am currently using inline-block in the live version, but that is unsupported by IE7

Comment: Found a way to have IE7 mimic inline-block, which is setting display: inline and zoom: 1

Answer (score 1):

In that case set the height on the div AND li's but make them inline, like Mr cletus says.

Or give up and use a `<table>`, although that'll get the css police banging on your door at 3am.

In the old days, we just used `<table>` and `<img>` and didn't know it was wrong. Like smoking in the 1970s, or listening to Rick Astley in the 1980's. We all did it, and still do once in a while when we think nobody is running us through a validator.

Comment: inline elements don't allow the setting of height